# Confused with SUID calculated during serialization of an object

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, serialization

I was reading serialization and confused with how SUID calculated during object serialization is passed to another machine. Below queries in context of object being serialized in one machine and passed to another.

a) Why suid is static ? 
b) If it is static and if we're only passing serialized object to another machine over network , then how come other JVM comes to know SUID calculated in first machine.
Since suid calculated is static and object is serialized , how other JVM comes to know SUID calculated for serialized object.

I gooogled but couldn't find appropriate ans. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood your question, you want to understand how SUID is used internally. Let me resume, in order to be sure that we share same information.

Serialization allows you to convert a live object to a sequence of byte, in order to store it somewhere or transmit it over a wire. More precisely, serialization saves the state of a object.

Serialization can be used also to send a object to a different environment, where a class with the same name is present too. Serialization contract tells that equal object types must have same SUID: so e.g. if you generate a serialization of a "Foo" object with SUID=1, it can be deserialized as a live instance of Foo only if related Foo class defines SUID=1 (or InvalidClassException will be thrown).

Deserialization process restores class fields (non-static and non-transient ones - that's why SUID is static), but SUID must be the same. Anyway, if you do not declare SUID, JVM evaluates one for you (as the hash of the class itself - not of the object) and uses it as default, adding it in the serialized object. Serialization specifications recommend to always define explicitely a SUID on serializable object, because there are no guarantees that automatic evaluation of SUID is the same on different JVM, so it can happen that SUID evaluation on serializer is different from the evaluation on deserializer (causing - as before - a InvalidClassException).

You can find further details here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#a4100

PS: you can find how custom SUID for a class is evaluated by looking at [java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(Class<?> cl)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java#ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID%28java.lang.Class%29) source code.

Comment: " Deserialization process restores class fields (non-static and non-transient ones - that's why SUID is static) " This is actually what i should've thought of. Thank you so much for great explanation.